# Node.js Interactive Window is not shown in Visual Studio 12

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Node.js as described here: https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation
Restarted my Visual Studio 12 Pro. Open View-Other Windows but cannot see 'Node.js Interactive Window' there. What I missed?

Comment: So to check, you installed: Node.js, Visual studio Pro, **And** the NTVS window that can be downloaded here? https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/releases/view/114437

Comment: @jessehouwing You're right. I didn't install NTVS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the Node.Js tool for Visual Studio you need to install:

1. Visual Studio Professional or better
2. Node.js ([x86](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22-x86.msi) or [x64](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/x64/node-v0.10.22-x64.msi))
3. [NTVS](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/releases/view/114437) itself

Comment: You no longer need VS Professional, VS 2015 Community (free) is fine.